# File separator character based on the operating system

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'd like to process a file path but its form depends on the operating system. Right now I'm using regular expressions to decide whether I should use '/' or '\'.

Is there a legitimate way to get the file separator character used by the operating system or the name of the operating system itself?

Context:

A third-party program creates an XML file with OS-dependent file paths in it (in "[DRIVE LETTER]:\...\..." or /.../..." format) and there's no access to the third-party program.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the XSLT `document` function to read in XML documents then its argument is a URL or list of nodes with URLs and with URLs the separator character is the slash `/` so doing `document('file:///C:/dir/subir/doc.xml')` should work with all XSLT processors on Windows and `document('file:/root/dir/subdir/doc/xml')` on LINUX. The same holds of course for relative URLs e.g `document('subdir1/subdir2/doc.xml')` is going to work with an XSLT processor, that's the advantage of URLs.

Comment: I updated my question with some context to make it clearer. Thanks for your response!

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you use exactly, on which platform exactly? A processor implemented in for instance Java often allows you to call extension functions or objects of the Java platform, that way you could read out a system property.